# how to install waf naxsi with a nginx system has been previously installed on centos 6.5 or 7?

Tags: nginx

I want to install a firewall to protect my server nginx and I found naxsi.
But all the results that I found on naxsi require installation by combining naxsi and nginx from source.
My nginx server is running and I do not want to risk re-install the entire nginx.
Does anyone know a tutorial on how to add naxsi to a nginx system is running?
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Because it is a compiled part in Nginx so you need to `./configure [arguments] | make | make install` to get it running. I don't see that as a problem though, it's straight forward and you should learn yourself how to do it to always keep up with the latest Nginx.
Download and extract the sources for Nginx and Naxsi. Run

```
$ nginx -V
```

To see previous configure arguments and add

```
--add-module=[path to naxsi]/naxsi_src
```

AS THE FIRST ARGUMENT. There are tutorials out there. Just go man. Go.